# twitter4j and twitter timestamp handling

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

According to the official twitter api page https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets) the "created_at" timestamp of each tweet is compiled according to "UTC time when this Tweet was created.".

Which UTC?

Because under the User struct inside the tweet struct i found the "utc_offset" of the user who created the tweet (https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/users).

So my question is if I can consider the "created_at" field of each tweet, independently of the used api, as UTC without offset.

And just to be sure if twitter4j change this behaviour since if I run a simple streaming test like this in italy where is UTC-1

```
String now = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    System.out.println("test run at: " + now); 
StatusListener listener = new StatusListener(){
        @Override
        public void onException(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatus(Status status) {
            System.out.println("@" + status.getId() + " - " + status.getCreatedAt().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice sdn) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrubGeo(long l, long l1) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStallWarning(StallWarning sw) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int i) {
        }
    };

    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
        .setOAuthConsumerKey ...


    TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
    twitterStream.addListener(listener);
    twitterStream.sample();
```

In result i obtain something like this:

```
run:
test run at: 20160921_084244
[Wed Sep 21 08:42:44 CEST 2016]Establishing connection.
[Wed Sep 21 08:42:46 CEST 2016]Connection established.
[Wed Sep 21 08:42:46 CEST 2016]Receiving status stream.
@778484603443113985 - Wed Sep 21 08:42:47 CEST 2016
@778484603443085312 - Wed Sep 21 08:42:47 CEST 2016
@778484603434795008 - Wed Sep 21 08:42:47 CEST 2016
@778484603443154945 - Wed Sep 21 08:42:47 CEST 2016
@778484603438923776 - Wed Sep 21 08:42:47 CEST 2016
@778484603434721280 - Wed Sep 21 08:42:47 CEST 2016
```

Where is easy to notice that the tweet are not showed in standard UTC it's seems that twitter4j automatically adjust them with local time zone.

Can someone help me in better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets) the result is in the following format

> "created_at":"Wed Aug 27 13:08:45 +0000 2008"

The `+0000` is the offset and Twitter4j only takes this input and create a `Date` Java variable. That means that the time displayed on the console depends on your configuration and your system.

Comment: So everything i got from twitter4j is already reported to my time zone or to utc-0?

Comment: Probably on your time zone, but that depends on your configuration. In my case is my time zone (-3 UTC). You could search some keyword and check it with a recent tweet by yourself

Comment: I run some test searching jap as a language with both stream api and search api and timestamps in both case are converted in my local timestamp. Now thanks to you this behaviour is clear. This way searching tweet is a lot more simple if the library do all the time zone conversions. Thanks a lot